# Django: How to show all images in images model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to show all images associated with the currently selected user

This is built off of this solved question: [django upload to image model with foreign key to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487037/django-upload-to-image-model-with-foreign-key-to-user)

Model.py

```
class Images(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', null=True, default='profile_image/none/no-img.png')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def index_account(request):
    args = {'user': request.user }
    return render(request, 've/cp/index_account.html', args)
```

Template > index_account.html

```
    <p><a href="{% url 've:edit_images' %}">Edit your images</a></p>
    # test to see if it worked w/o if
    {{ user.images.image}}

    # ideal solution
    {% if user.images.images %}
        {% for img in user.images %}
        <img src="{{ user.images.image.url }}"><br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <p>No images</p>

    {% endif %}

    <br>
    <hr>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided is not going to work for what you want. So here is an example of something that probably will:

**Example**

views.py

```
from app_name.models import Images 
@login_required
def index_account(request):
    images = Images.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 've/cp/index_account.html', {"images": images})
```

index_account.html

```
<p><a href="{% url 've:edit_images' %}">Edit your images</a></p>

# ideal solution
{% if images %}
    {% for img in images %}
    <img src="{{ img.url }}"><br>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
<p>No images</p>

{% endif %}

<br>
<hr>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, the if statment looks like it's working because I am no longer getting "No images" however no images show. Any good way to debug this?

Comment: eh check in your django admin whether you have any images, and also I am not entirely sure if that was the way to show the images (`img.url`), maybe look into that?

Comment: @AlexWinkler just did a quick research try using `img.image.url` or `img.image.path` Hope this helps!

Comment: Ya, I have several images associated to this user. Also, I have media URL and static files working. In extended user profile I added image field and I can show images via the field using user.profile.image.url. So it's weird that  Also I have media URL and static files working. In extended user profile I added image field and I can show fields user.images.image.url doesn't work

Comment: Would love to upvote but need more rep first. Will do when I have it. Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexWinkler no worries, glad to help! Enjoy the +10 as well :)